# SATA power connector usage

Tags: power-supply, power, connector, sata

I'm making a small device that I want to power by the sata power connector/ATX PSU. It needs 5v and 12v power supply. This device will use standard 15pin SATA power male connector to get the power from the PSU. According to the specs I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA#Standard_connector), there are 3 5v and 3 12v pins, some of them are longer and used for precharging. My question - is it ok in the device to shorten all 5v together to get more power, and also the same for 12v and ground? I suppose so because on all my PSUs there's just one wire comes to the SATA power connector for each voltage, but is it standard and stated somewhere in the specs?

Also, there are power disable and Staggered spinup/activity pins - can they just be ignored?

Thank you.

Comment: When you ask "is it ok to shorten all 5v together to get more power, and also the same for 12v and ground?" Do you mean on the device side or connector side?

Comment: @ccolton I am building a device, so I want to connect all 5v pins together, all 12v and all ground pins as well on the device's male connector. Will edit question to clarify

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what the longer pins are for, shortening them won't make a difference. They will still deliver the same amount of power when the connector is fully connected, and they're only working to your advantage to avoid sparks if you're hot-plugging your device in.

Comment: @ccolton I suppose you misunderstood the way it works. According to the specs, one pin is attended for precharging so it is longer than others. Others intended "To reduce impedance and increase current capability, each voltage is supplied by three pins in parallel, though one pin in each group is intended for precharging (see below). Each pin should be able to carry 1.5 A."

Comment: I see, you want full power the moment you plug it in? So you can get 4.5A right off the bat, and not accidentally fry the longer pin?

Comment: @ccoltonI just want to understand is it ok to connect pins with the same voltage together so it won't harm the psu or other devices. It's not related to the current or power consumed

Comment: Clarification: do you want to 'shorten' them (make them shorter) or do you want to 'short' them (connect them together)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's totally ok to wire all pins of the same voltage in parallel. That's how they're wired inside the connector anyway, so don't worry about it. The power disable pin is not used often on standard ATX power supplies, so don't worry about it unless you're plugging you device into some server appliance that might have a backplane that uses the power disable pin. Big server drive sleds use this pin, but standard PSUs don't. Same goes for staggered spinup, if you're connecting your device to a standard ATX power supply, just treat it like a GND and wire all the GNDs in parallel.